# Error excepción. No sé resolverlo

Tags: java

Buenas a todos, estoy trabajando en un proyecto que va bastante bien, a excepción siendo redundantes de una excepción que salta y no sé porque. Os adjunto el código donde me surge el error.

Basicamente se trata de una función que me lea de un fichero y me vaya creando objetos en función de lo que lee. La cosa es que lo crea todo genial, pero cuando ejecuto, me salta la excepción porque me sale el mensaje de error "I/O Error while extracting information from de file. Y me gustaría saber si podéis ayudarme a evitarlo, la cosa está en que el buffer.close() que aparece subrayado en amarillo, me india un warning de null pointer access, pero no sé donde colocarlo para cerrar el buffer del fichero una vez leido completamente.

Como digo el resto funciona perfetamente, ya que atrapa la excepción y continua ejecutando.

Gracias por vuestro tiempo y ayuda de antemano!

EDITO: Usando el método e.printStackTrace() me indica que el fallo ocurre en la línea del split, aunque no sé porqué, leo de un fichero de entrada así:

2

3 4

5 6

Donde 2 es el numero de actividades, el 3 el inicio y 4 el final de esa actividad, lo mismo para el 5 y el 6

```
public static void giveInfo(BufferedReader buffer){

    try{            
        String numberOfTask = buffer.readLine();
        int numberOfTaskInt = Integer.parseInt(numberOfTask); //This is the number of activities
        //DEPURE
        System.out.println("Number of activities is: "+numberOfTaskInt);            
        int counter=0;
        while(buffer!=null){ //Reading the file to the bottom
            String line= buffer.readLine();
            String[] parts = line.split(" "); //Manage the info
            Activities a = new Activities(counter,Integer.parseInt(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1])); //Creating the activity  
            tableOfActivities.add(a); //Insert the activity in my table
            counter++; //Increasing the counter because i have assigned one activity                    
            }
        buffer.close(); //When have read the file, we will close it                     
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("I/O Error while extracting information from the file");
    }       
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor, copia el código directamente en el editor en lugar de poner imágenes. Si la imagen caduca, la publicación perdería sentido. [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/64884/edit) y añade el código.

Comment: Respecto a tu pregunta, realiza un `e.printStackTrace()` en el catch para que veas el rastreo de pila y puedas ver qué origina el problema.

Comment: okey, ahora mismo lo corrijo, gracias

Comment: Utilizando el e.printStackTrace() que me has dicho, me dice que la excepcion salta en la parte del split, pero no se me ocurre el motivo. El fichero del que leo tiene en la primera línea un número, en la segunda linea dos numeros y en la tercera dos numeros. El primero es un numero de actividades, en las lineas siguientes, el primer numero es el de inicio de la actividad, y el segundo del fin de la actividad. Estoy dandole vueltas pero no sé que fallo será, si logro resolverlo aviso por aquí. Y gracias!

Comment: ¿Ves que tipo de excepción te dice? Existen varias. Se me ocurre que puedes tener un NullPointerException.

Comment: Si, es un NullPointerException, pero se supone que el while(buffer!=null) deberia evitarlo, es decir, no lee nada y directamente cerraría con buffer.close()

Comment: El NPE lo estás obteniendo porque `buffer.readLine` está devolviendo null. Puedes comprobrarlo imprimiendo `line` antes de hacer el split.

Comment: Efectivamente era eso, la condición estaba mal puesta, en vez de un while(buffer!=null) debería ser while(buffer.readLine()!=null). Pues muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, llevaba un par de días que no lo sacaba y era esta tontería, pero era incapaz de verlo, de nuevo, gracias por tu tiempo y tu ayuda

Comment: Siempre es grato ayudar. Si tienes más preguntas, no dudes en publicarlas.

Comment: @OnlyDavies aunque el problema parece obvio, cuando preguntes, trata de agregar la mayor información posible, código, tipo de error, en donde sucede, si esposible el stacktrace.

Comment: Sugiero que, o bien @GustavoGarcia publique una respuesta a fin de que sea marcada como solución por el OP, o bien que la pregunta sea considerada como un problema que no se puede reproducir y sea cerrada/eliminada. Lo digo para que no vayan quedando preguntas abiertas en las que entremos con intención de responder cuando ya el asunto ha sido resuelto.

Comment: @A.Cedano pensé que ya había votado para cerrar por error typo. Lo acabo de hacer; creo que la pregunta no amerita una respuesta.